# how to update invoice in Retail Managment system

Tags: c#

I have created RMS(Retail Managment System) in which I want to update Invoice..

I am confused that when we update the invoice, it shows the previous amount and Now sale amount and grand total in Invoice.

When we want to update in previous two invoices each invoice have different previous amount, so it changes over all balance of the customer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I know about RMS, it's not possible to "update" closed invoice, you create new one.
Upon creation of historical transaction you will need to re-calculate the balance on hand again.

There are ways to make this re-calculation easier - like saving for each day the BOH (balance on hand) and do the calculation for the day of the historical transaction and , and just add the delta to the aggregated result per day